# How to show select menu for two models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I'm using [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and don't how you would show the values of 2 associations.

A Price can belong to a service or product but not both at the same time.

```
Price
 # service_id, product_id
 belongs_to :services # service.name
 belongs_to :products # product.name
end
```

Instead having my simple form look like this:

```
<%= f.association :product, :input_html => { :class => "span5 } %>
<%= f.association :service, :input_html => { :class => "span5 } %>
```

I want to turn it into one field instead.

What is the way with `simple_form_for`?

What about with a regular `form_for`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better way to do is to use polymorphic association.

```
class Price
    belongs_to :pricable, polymorphic: true
end

class Product
    has_one :price, as: :priceable
end

class Service
    has_one :price, as: :priceable
end
```

Then, in your form, you can use:

```
<%= form_for [@priceable, Price.new]
```

where @priceable is a product or a service.